# How to convert dot notation string array into an object JavaScript and render to table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this data:

```
const data = [
  {
    _id: '1',
    status: 'active',
    user: {
      email: 'one@mail.com',
      provider: 'google',
      profile: {
        image: 'https://example.com/image1.jpg',
      },
    },
  },
    {
      _id: '2',
      status: 'inactive',
      user: {
        email: 'two@mail.com',
        provider: 'github',
        profile: {
          image: 'https://example.com/image2.jpg',
        },
      },
    },
]


const head = ['_id', 'status', 'email', 'image']

const body = ['_id', 'status', 'user.email', 'user.profile.image']
```

I want to display in the table dynamically only show the string in the body array.

I tried and it worked _id, and status but not the string which contains **dot**

Here is what I have tried:

```
data.map((item) => (
  <tr key={item._id}>
    {body.map((i, index) => (
      <td key={index}>{item[i]}</td>
    ))}
  </tr>
))
```

Comment: is it react lib

Comment: this is supported in lodash with get in case you are using it. but something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-and-arrays-by-string-path

Comment: @MohitSharma I forget to mention it. Yes it react

Comment: a bad way of achieving this using eval. `eval(`item.${i}`)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my way to achieve your desire output.
use this function

```
function getDeepObjValue (item, s) {
   return s.split('.').reduce((p, c) => {
      p = p[c];
      return p;
   }, item);
};
```

use it like this

```
data.map((item) => {
    return (
       <tr key={item._id}>
          {body.map((keys, i) => {
             return <td key={i}>{getDeepObjValue(item, keys)}</td>;
          })}
       </tr>
    );
})
```

and if you want to check demo [click here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6ivxaj?file=src%2FTable.js)

Answer (score 1):

If your body data is not dynamic you can do :

```
data.map((item) => (
  <tr key={item._id}>
      <>
      <td key={index}>{item._id}</td>
      <td key={index}>{item.status}</td>
      <td key={index}>{item.user.email}</td>
      <td key={index}>{item.user.profile.image}</td>
      <>
  </tr>
))
```

else you can use

```
const deeper = (data, array) => {
  if(array.length > 1){
    return deeper(data[array[0]], array.slice(1, array.length))
  } else {
    return data[array[0]]
  }
}
```

with

```
data.map((item) => (
  <tr key={item._id}>
    {body.map((i, index) => (
      <td key={index}>{deeper(item, i.split('.'))}</td>
    ))}
  </tr>
))
```

Something like that