# How to access a nested property of an object using a string?

Tags: javascript

I have the following string:

```js
const str = "prop1.prop2.prop3"
```

I want to use this string to access the property prop3 of the following object:

```js
const obj = {
   prop1: {
      prop2:{
         prop3:{
            // ---- destination point
         }
      }
   }
}
```

But I'm not able to figure out how to do it?
there must be something that keeps adding the `obj[currentProp]` so on and so on. and.. isn't there a quicker method? I'm afraid I'm wasting my time on something that can be achieved more easily

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically updating a JavaScript object from a string path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15092912/dynamically-updating-a-javascript-object-from-a-string-path)

Comment: This is a duplicate, but I can't find any of the old questions. You have to either write your own function or find one in a library. The language itself does not have a way to do this.

Comment: lodash for example has set and get which are quite handy

Comment: This used to be called "object graph navigation", but that term may have faded into obscurity. There is/was a very nice library for Java (not JavaScript) called "OGNL", object graph navigation language.

Comment: does this works for you [mpath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mpath)

Comment: @bogdanoff, yes.

Comment: @cmgchess, I'm using lodash, then great

Comment: @thomas, perhaps yes, but the question is too much complicated and the answers are even more complicated

Comment: @thomas, and the guy in the question is trying to access the prop in the object using the delimiter ">", while I'm trying to access it normally using the javascript way object dot notation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert dot notation string array into an object JavaScript and render to table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72800339/how-to-convert-dot-notation-string-array-into-an-object-javascript-and-render-to)

Comment: @MohitSharma, of course yes, but the guy is using React, how about keeping this question as a clean and simple reference for everyone?

Comment: @Normal but function work same for all with same requirements use `getDeepObjValue` to get your output.

Comment: @MohitSharma. yes that's, true. but I also want the community to benefit as well. by asking an abstract and straightforward question. not everyone is using React. If I'm a beginner and I was to read that question, I wouldn't understand the JSX part of the questions/answers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This would be my approach:

```js
const access = (path, object) => {
  return path.split('.').reduce((o, i) => o[i], object)
}

const obj = {
  prop1: {
    prop2: {
      prop3: {
        value: 'foo'
      }
    }
  }
}

const str = 'prop1.prop2.prop3'

console.log(access(str, obj)) // {"value": "foo"}
```

Comment: aha, great then using array.reduce, I was thinking all the time of .map and .forEach

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `split` with `forEach` as follows:

```js
const str = "prop1.prop2.prop3"

const obj = {
   prop1: {
      prop2:{
         prop3:{
            a: "b",
            c: "d"
         }
      }
   }
}

var srch = obj;

str.split(".").forEach(item => (srch = srch[item]));

console.log(srch); // { a: "b", c: "d"}
console.log(obj);
```

`split` converts `str`'s value into an array, which is then looped and on each iteration, `srch` gets one level deeper.

Comment: but that modifies the original obj in the memory because that's what `var srch = obj` exactly does

Comment: @Normal no, it does not. `srch` is a reference to a variable. If you say `a = 1; b = 1; a = 2`, that does not change `b`. Note that I did not change your elements of `obj`, I changed only the reference. I have edited my Fiddle to `console.log(obj);`. If you test it, you will see that `srch` is properly computed, while `obj` remained unchanged.

Comment: yes, you're right

Answer (score 0):

### different ways to access a nested property of an object

using a function `accessDeepProp` with two arguments the object and path of the nested property!

##### Recursive way:

```js
function accessDeepProp(obj, path) {
  if (!path) return obj;
  const properties = path.split(".");
  return accessDeepProp(obj[properties.shift()], properties.join("."));
}
```

##### For-loop way:

```js
function accessDeepProp(obj, path) {
  const properties = path.split(".");
  for (let i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
    if (!obj) return null;
    obj = obj[properties[i]];
  }
  return obj;
}
```

##### Eval way: [never_use_eval!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!)

```js
function accessDeepProp(objName, path) {
  try {
    return eval(`${objName}.${path}`);
  } catch (e) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

*you could also use [lodash get method](https://lodash.com/docs#get)*

Answer (score -1):

This is the shortest solution, and it supports arrays and ['bracket notation']. Just don't run it against malicious user input.

Update: a better(?) version without `eval`.

```js
const obj = {
  prop1: {
    prop2: {
      prop3: {
        value: 'foo'
      }
    }
  }
}

const str = 'prop1.prop2.prop3'
//console.log(eval("obj." + str))

// a code without eval
var value = (Function("return obj." + str))();
console.log(value);
```

Comment: no, it will be downvoted with reason; since eval has risk if you use it just *Never use eval()*

Comment: Is using `Function(body)` considered a better option"?

Comment: It has similar problems, and in this case there's a simpler and safer solution.

Comment: if you add try catch it would be much safer! see my answer!

Comment: @Pointy Which lacks features vs the `eval`/`Function` version. I disagree to *never* use `eval`. If it's my data (and not arbitrary user data) I think it's ok to.

Comment: @ITgoldman yea "never" is a strong word. The main problem I have with `eval()` is about performance: V8 will not bother to optimize a function with an `eval()` call, because it really has no idea what it might do.